# How to form ticket fare ascending and descending order form array in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa

My Array Values are

20,
 30,
 25,
 50,
 "600/500",
 "410/360"

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Sort Descriptor:

**For Ascending:**

```
NSSortDescriptor *descriptor=[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"self" ascending:YES];
NSArray *descriptors=[NSArray arrayWithObject: descriptor];
NSArray *reverseOrder=[yourArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:descriptors];
```

**For Descending:**

```
NSSortDescriptor *descriptor=[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"self" ascending:NO];
NSArray *descriptors=[NSArray arrayWithObject: descriptor];
NSArray *reverseOrder=[yourArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:descriptors];
```

Comment: Hi Bhaskar Your answaer will come this order.  20,
    25,
    30,
    "410/360",
    50,
    "600/500"